# Expo/React Native - all animations suddenly stopped working

Tags: react-native, expo

All animations in my android Expo app suddenly stopped working (when running expo server locally).
I was playing with a custom drawer menu. I wanted to add swipe gestures so I followed this [tutorial](https://code.likeagirl.io/creating-tinder-like-swipe-component-with-react-native-3bf15e6be7e3) but I didn't finish and I swear that all animations were working fine when I left the project.

In the afternoon I came back to the project and I noticed that animations are broken.

Animations show only the first and last frames without a transition in between. This applies to all animations including ones in components from Ui Kitten ([TabView](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/4.x/components/tab-view/overview#tabview)). I went back in the git history to the last build I published on Google Play, I removed `node_modules` and `.expo` and run `npm i`. I am sure that everything worked fine in that version because this version is on Google Play but the animations are broken on localhost o_O

I'm absolutely clueless about what can be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some hours of playing around with the problem I realized, that there was nothing wrong with the code. As soon as I disabled the debugger everything went back to normal